# Specific applicationIdSuffix prevents app from starting

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, android-multidex

In this specific case the applicationIdSuffix `.accept` suddenly prevents this app from starting. `onCreate` of the extended Application class does not get called. There's also no errors in logcat. The app starts and the screen remains white.

Another applicationIdSuffix like `.local` works and also reverting the code to a state where I'm sure the accept suffix worked, suddenly doesn't work anymore (and so does other devices or different Android versions). Building on another machine makes no difference. I really narrowed it down to just the specific suffix `.accept` not working. It seems like there suddenly is a conflict with this suffix.

Has anyone ecountered this before and know what could be the reason? The solution is to simply change the suffix for now, but I'm just baffled as to why this doesn't work all of the sudden.

Comment: It would be helpful if you publish some logs and your gradle file.

Comment: As I said, the logs don't show anything because the app doesn't even start. My gradle file is also unrelated since I've narrowed it down to the applicationId(Suffix).

Comment: What happens if you changed the name of the suffix to something else, does it work? Try `./gradlew clean assembleAccept --stacktrace` and see if you get something weird in the logs that can give some hints, assuming you have a flavor called `accept` that adds such sufix.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem in one project I was working.

Turns out the problem was in the Firebase google-services.json and not in the applicationIdSuffix. The package/bundle specified at the bundle simply stopped working, retroactively at it.

The solution was using another suffix, registering it on Firebase, and downloading the new google-services.json.

Comment: Worked for me! Thank you :)

Comment: I haven't been able to test this yet, only our client has access to the Firebase console for this project. Once we get access I will try it out and come back to it. I do think you're right though.